# Deadlock error in the application while load-testing using JMeter

Tags: sql, deadlock, jmeter

I am load-testing my application using JMeter.

I am creating 2 threads right now, that update the database simultaneously (Ramp-up period is 0). But I am getting the following error:

> Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

I have included the deadlock graph along with this.
Does anyone have any inputs on this?

[image: Deadlock Graph]

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with JMeter. Your application is prone to deadlocks.

This might or might not be a bug. If your are ok with deadlocks occurring rarely, no worry (be aware that a request receiving a deadlock is likely to crash).

If you are not ok with the possibility of deadlocks this is a bug that needs to be fixed. You can find information about doing that elsewhere.